# Difference reification and implementation

Tags: theory

Wikipedia defines [reification](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reification_%28computer_science%29) as:

> Reification is the process by which an abstract idea about a computer
>   program is turned into an explicit data model or other object created
>   in a programming language.

Definition of 
[implementation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implementation) sounds:

> Implementation is the realization of an application, or execution of a
>   plan, idea, model, design, specification, standard, algorithm, or
>   policy.

When I was looking into meaning of reification it definition striked me as something for which I would use word **implementation** e.g. translating theory into practice in one of possible ways.

Is implementation superset of reification?  What is the difference between these two words?

Answer (score 0):

I'd say you're about right when you hypothesize that a reification is a subset of an implementation.

Reification applies to an abstraction to be transposed into a concrete object whereas implementation is about the whole program.
For example, if you were to implement a video game (thus the implementation) you may need to translate abstract concepts such as coordinates into concrete objects, i.e.`Point` structures (which would be ONE reification).